# How do I add a scrollbar to a Rofi theme?

Tags: themes, scrollbar

OS: 18.04

`man rofi` describes *rofi* as

> A window switcher, application launcher, ssh dialog and dmenu
>   replacement

There are twenty-five themes to choose from in `/usr/share/rofi/themes` by running `rofi-theme-selector`. However, the "default" theme isn't listed there.

The image below shows the window generated by running `rofi-theme-selector`:

[image: rofi-theme-selector]

A scrollbar is present with the default theme. However, none of the other themes display this scrollbar. The image below shows a preview of the solarized theme.

[image: Solarized theme lacking a scrollbar]

Is it possible to make the solarized theme display a scrollbar?

Answer (score 2):

I first wanted to compare the code of default and solarized themes to see why the only the former theme displayed a scrollbar. However, it appears that the default theme is baked into Rofi itself and so such a comparison isn't possible.

I then installed Rofi in Ubuntu 19.10 and ran `rofi-theme-selector`. Some of the themes in 19.10's `/usr/share/rofi/themes`, including *Arc-Dark* did have scrollbars.

A comparison of *Arc-Dark* and *solarized* indicated that, in the former, code for the scrollbar section had the line

```
handle-color: @normal-foreground;
```

whereas the solarized theme lacks this line.

So changing

```
#scrollbar {
    width:        4px ;
    border:       0;
    handle-width: 8px ;
    padding:      0;
}
```

in the solarized theme in 18.04 to

```
#scrollbar {
    width:        4px ;
    border:       0;
    handle-color: @normal-foreground;
    handle-width: 8px ;
    padding:      0;
}
```

does the job and the modified solarized theme in 18.04 (and 19.10) now displays a scrollbar:

[image: Solarized theme with scrollbar]

---

- some rofi themes just don't have a scrollbar section. (I didn't look at these themes further.)
- another aspect to check is whether the `listview` section of the theme has `scrollbar: false;`. That would need changing to `scrollbar: true;`
- themes can be instead placed in `$HOME/.config/rofi` in which case the rofi command would need to include `-theme ...` where `...` is the theme's prefix. So, if there's `$HOME/.config/rofi/my_solarized.rasi`, the command to run rofi would include `-theme my_solarized`.